# Биржевая стратегия

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, pycharm

**Цель:** Вводится цена акций в первый, второй и т. д. дни, ноль — сигнал остановки. Возможно, сначала цена уменьшается. В какой-то момент цена начинает расти. Мы покупаем акции в первый день, когда их цена превышает цену в предыдущий день. После этого в какой-то момент цена акций начинает уменьшаться. Мы продаём акции в первый же день, как только их цена становится меньше цены в предыдущие дни. Возможно, после этого цены как-то ещё меняются.

*Программа должна вывести цену акций, по которой мы их купили, цену, по которой продали, и выгоду с каждой акции (возможно, отрицательную).*

**Формат ввода:**
Несколько целых чисел — цены акций в последовательные дни. 
Число 0 — сигнал прекращения ввода цен.

**Формат вывода:**
Три целых числа — цена покупки, цена продажи, выгода.

**Ввод:** 32 30 31 34 38 37 39

**Вывод:** 31 37 6 (в одну строчку)

*Мой вариант(неудача)*

```
qwerty=0
a=''
while a!='0':
    a=input()
    b=input()
    if a>b:
        qwerty=b
    elif a==0 or b==0:
        print(qwerty,)
    elif a<b:
```

**Не следует пользоваться советами этого робота в реальной жизни!!!**

Comment: У вас приведенный код даже работать не должен

Comment: Вначале введите все данные в список.

Comment: напишите на rfpro.ru

Comment: Когда все числа будут в списке, циклом проходим и ищем нужные дни.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас вообще код бредовый. На быструю руку:

```
b = st = end = 0
while  (True):
    a=int(input())
    if a == 0:
      break;
    if b!=0:
      if st==0:
        if a > b:
          st = a
      elif end==0:
        if a<b:
          end =a
    b = a
print(st,end,end-st)
```